# Post to group via Facebook Graph API is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I have created an API to post in a facebook group. I have installed the app on this group and I got the approval of using groups_access_member_info, publish_to_groups, Groups API.
But when i try to post using this API it shows me the error.

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: POST https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0//feed?access_token=EAAdDfw1wYHMBAKgXanbDHMHtKK04O5jO5gvQZCjOdHd38ni9D2x5IFDXkOQamJDYNoCBwbsJl0uZC6xBVgAvdYQb8xQJqwYqJvwSZBydCzPLy6MvyaiCtmXUPZA77QM0Q4ZAsuUgvQfkRyz4ePRMz6J7FndtVTDiuOeuHQ1WvZBBTMg7sMBSEp45LmEKE4m3EZD resulted in a 403 Forbidden response:{"error":{"message":"(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\n          either p (truncated...)
```

Could you please help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the error and do what it say?

Comment: @WizKid Yes, I did. The app is installed in the group, got the approval of all required access. But still, it shows the same error.

Comment: The error message above is truncated, make sure you check the full one. Debug your access token, to verify what permissions it actually contains.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I am trying to do the same here and my app never gets aprove by Facebook ;(